# Why does this closure never work on Safari Mobile?

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari

On every browser I've tested, with the exception of Safari Mobile, the following code works as expected: when a button is clicked, an alert is shown. However, on Safari Mobile, the closure doesn't appear to be "closing over" a variable defined in an if-block, and so the alert doesn't fire.

Can someone explain this?

```
const button = document.getElementById("clickme");

if (true) {
  // move this outside of the 'if' block and it works
  // on Safari Mobile
  let greeting = "hello world";
  function clicked() {
    alert(greeting);
  }
  button.onclick = clicked;
}
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/argmi/pen/poaKgYr

Comment: I think I've seen a previous question where this was determined to be a bug. It's related to the way the `function` declaration is hoisted.

Comment: Could be you blocked redundant "alert windows" on that device already?

Comment: Try using `const clicked = () => alert(greeting);`

Comment: @Andy It's just a minimal demo to create a local scope for the variable. Presumably the real code has a real condition.

Comment: @Andy it does in this case because it is affecting how the javascript compiler scopes variables on Safari.

Comment: @Barmar, I've confirmed that your suggestion works correctly on Safari https://codepen.io/argmi/pen/abqKNJM Strange! I'll dig around for the previous question that you mentioned. If I can find that, I'll reference it in the answer here.

Comment: I found it, see the linked question.